# Access to publicly available project with all the artefacts (files) created during the development

Tags: reference-request, software-engineering, data-sets

Does anyone know where I could get an access to a project that contains all the artefacts (documents) that were created during the development? So I would like to get all the word, pdf, power designer, etc. files as well as all the source code. If possible, I would prefer that all this files are stored in some of the software reporitories.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is to go with major open source projects (Apache, Open Office, Mozilla, MySql, perhaps Linux).  Since these are done by large online communities all communication occurs online through bug databases and forums or mailing lists (which are usually archived).  If they do code reviews they may be archived with a tool like Review Board or will be done through the official archived mailing lists.  It seems unlikely that you will find a non-open source project/company willing to provide such detailed information.

An example of an academic software engineering study which quite successfully used open source artifacts is:

> [Shan Lu, Soyeon Park, Eunsoo Seo, Yuanyuan Zhou: Learning from mistakes: a comprehensive study on real world concurrency bug characteristics. (ASPLOS-XIII):329-339, 2008](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~shanlu/paper/asplos122-lu.pdf).

Prof. Y.Y. Zhou's research team at UCSD has done a variety of other studies mining open source bug databases to understand bug or failure characteristics.  http://opera.ucsd.edu/pub_system_depend.html#characteristic-study